# Error during Xcode Component Installation

Tags: xcode, xcode4, installation, xcode4.3

I just installed a software update that I was prompted for, presumably affecting Xcode.  Now when I start Xcode, I am presented with a dialog box which states that Xcode must install the Mobile Device Framework before continuing.  When I try to do this, after providing my password, it fails with "An unknown error occurred. See the install log for more details."  I do not see anything useful in install.log that identifies the problem.  I've tried re-installing multiple times and rebooting to no avail.

I'm currently running Xcode 4.3.  Perhaps I need to upgrade to 4.4?  Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: Upgrading to Xcode 4.4 solves it.

Comment: https://github.com/wigl/iSimulator/releases/tag/3.3.0

Answer (score 165):

This problem has once again appeared in Xcode 11.1 and is caused by an invalid certificate that expired some day in October 2019.

You can work around the problem by temporarily changing the system date to before the certificate expiration date.

In the case of Xcode 11, set the system date to Oct 3, 2019, run Xcode, then change the date back after the components have installed.

Answer (score 42):

In Xcode version 4.3.1 (4E1019), I suspect that I got the problem after an iTunes update this morning. Found the following somewhere on the web:

- Go to Applications folder
- Right click Xcode
- Click <kbd>Show Package Contents</kbd>

Then navigate to  <kbd>Contents/Resources/Packages</kbd>. Double click on <kbd>Install MobileDevice.pkg</kbd>.

Comment: This worked great for the following error `UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for key 'initializationClass' of extension 'Xcode.IDEDeferredInitialization.GPUDebuggeriOSPlatformSupport.GPUiOSInitializer' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.gpu.GPUDebuggeriOSSupport'`

Comment: It said "installing additional components" after installing the package. Then it crashed again!

Comment: For me it does not even ask to install additional components again

Comment: I have installed all the packages in `/Contents/Resources/Packages/` and it worked

Answer (score 30):

Just change the date to October 2019:

[image]

Comment: It's so weird, but this solution worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried installing the required components:

[image]

but I had the same issue:

[image]

I recommend @Darren answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58651694/7602110) but I tried another way, which was uninstalling Xcode and installing it back again, is not the best way to go, because we all know how long that Xcode takes to install, but it also works and was worth sharing.

Answer (score 1):

im resolver that change terminal date for example:

sudo date 103106

Comment: please elaborate on why this will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me after an update to Big Sur version.
A very similar solution as reported here by @cugino worked to me, as follows:

- Go to "Applications" folder > Right click Xcode > Click Show Package Contents > Then navigate to Contents/Resources/Packages.
- Double click on Install **XcodeSystemResources**.pkg.

Answer (score 0):

Using cugino's answer above solved it for me. In my case, the certificate used to sign the .pkg file had expired. This may be the reason for anyone experiencing this after February 14, 2015

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie in iOS development

I was facing same problem while trying to install XCode 6.4 on my 2009 mac pro 13inch with macOS yosemite. I do not know why, just after I changed the system time back to 10th October 2019 according to one of the answers in this thread and click on "try again" button, XCode was finally installed and running!

After this, I changed my system time back to current time (chose the automatic date and time option) and everything works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change Time in OS x10.11 or ....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /path/to/Xcode.app
```

```
$ sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```