# Xcode unable to start due to install additional components failing after automatic update MacOS 10.15.2

Tags: xcode11, macos-catalina

Got my mac autoupdated, upon restart, I cannot use Xcode due to "install additional required components" dialog. The install prompts for password, then fails every time with the same message. The log mentions some cert expired.

**How do I fix this failure to start loop without updating Xcode?** (Currently I'm trying to update Xcode to 11.3 as a workaround, not sure if this will work)

[image]

[image]

> 2020-01-03 16:36:05+07 Alexanders-MacBook-Air Xcode[721]: Package
>   Authoring Error: PackageInfo bundle reference found without top-level
>   bundle definition. Bundle will be skipped: 
>       2020-01-03 16:36:05+07 Alexanders-MacBook-Air Xcode[721]: Package: PKLeopardPackage 
>   Failed to verify with error: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain
>   Code=102 "The package “MobileDevice.pkg” is untrusted."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The package “MobileDevice.pkg” is
>   untrusted., NSURL=MobileDevice.pkg --
>   file:///Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/,
>   PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.apple.pkg.MobileDevice,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb0be138100 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-2147409654 "CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED" UserInfo={SecTrustResult=5,
>   PKTrustLevel=PKTrustLevelExpiredCertificate,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED}}}

Answer (score 5):

have you tried to set system date as 3 oct 2019 and retry? I got a reference here -> [Error during Xcode Component Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444656/error-during-xcode-component-installation)

Comment: I can confirm that changing the clock to some day in October, 2019 solves the problem. The reason is given in the cross reference.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling the Xcode and re-downloading an entire XIP.